# how can i print a code like matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I write this code but i want be print like a matrix ,how can i do it?

```
block = [1,2,3,4]
for i in block:
    for j in block:
        print("\n",j)

    print(" ")
```

i want to be like this

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: What exactly should the output look like?

Comment: not quite sure what you want. Can you add an example to your question? How does your code know what the dimension of your matrix are?

Comment: do you know how to print the elements of `block` on a single line?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Define your elements
block = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Repeat a certain number of times (i.e. 4, the length of the matrix)
for i in range(len(block)):
    # Print all the numbers 'joined' together with a space
    # Noting that they have to be strings to use the 'join' function
    # Python automatically puts a newline with the print
    print(" ".join([str(x) for x in block]))
```

The basis behind this code is to print the [formatted] list a certain amount of times, namely the length of the list times. In this case it is 4.

Each time we iterate through, we print the formatted array, which is simply the array with a space between each character. The `[str(x) for x in block]` is just because 'join' requires the values to be strings.

Comment: can you help OP understand what you're doing? Just doing their homework for them doesn't really help them...

Comment: I agree with @MarcusMüller  You should give OP the logic for it and why their code was not what they wanted

Comment: @MarcusMüller . Changes made. Hopefully it makes more sense for the OP

Comment: Nice, thanks, Larry!

Comment: Another way is to use `unpacking` - replace last statement with this:  `print(*block)` will do it.